# Mails are Stay in Queue for Specific Domains

Tags: centos, postfix

In my server I run Plesk 11 (Centos 5 x64), I have many domains. Two of them cannot receive emails. All their emails stay in the queue.

The message I take from the maillog is the following

```
...relay=plesk_virtual, delay=2457, delays=2457/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: fork_execv: execv("/usr/sbin/sendmail") failed: Exec format error 4.2.1 Message can not be delivered at this time
```

Can anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

The `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --with-spam`, doesn't solve my problem.

Thank you

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

`Exec format error` suggests that the executable in question (`/usr/sbin/sendmail`) is in a foreign format that the system doesn't understand how to execute.

- Double check the output of `uname -a` to make sure that this system is in fact running a 64-bit kernel (someone might have botched a kernel upgrade).
- If the running kernel is in fact 64-bit, try to identify how a binary from a different architecture entirely ended up on your system.
- Expect to run into this problem again with other binaries until you've identified how this happened.

If you're running a chrooted configuration, remember that the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` path is relative to the chroot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I check all of these, but I think is something else.Maybe It's a problem with symlinks(?). I run the following commands : # ll /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr  4 21:30 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta

ll /etc/alternatives/mta
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Apr  5 12:05 /etc/alternatives/mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

]# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/postfix
postfix-2.8.4-12052415

Are these correct?